# Issue outputting queryset results and <a> elements in Django admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have these models:

```
class Academic(models.Model):

    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    forename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.surname, self.forename)

class Partner(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Organisation name")

class ResearchActivity(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    academic = models.ManyToManyField(Academic, blank=True)
    partner = models.ManyToManyField(Partner, blank=True)
```

I want to output the academics linked to a partner via the `ResearchActivity` model. I have this decorator in my admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Partner)
class PartnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ('get_academic_links',)

    @admin.display(description='Academic link(s)')
    def get_academic_links(self, obj):
       
        for ac in ResearchActivity.objects.filter(partner=obj.id).values_list('academic', flat=True).distinct():
            return mark_safe('<a href={}>' + ac.surname + '</a>', ac)
```

It sort of works. If I return only `ac` then I get the ID of that academic. I would expect to get the 'name, surname', as per `def __str__(self):` decorator.

More importantly, if I try to construct an hyperlink (see code above) the admin outputs a '-' and nothing else. What am I missing?

**Update**

This code:

```
        academics_set = list(ResearchActivity.objects.filter(partner=obj.id).values_list('academic__forename', 'academic__surname').distinct())
       return academics_set
```

returns

```
[('forename1', 'surname1'), ('forename2', 'surname2'), ('forename3', 'surname3')]
```

Whils this code:

```
        academics_set = list(ResearchActivity.objects.filter(partner=obj.id).values_list('academic__forename', 'academic__surname').distinct())
        for ac in academics_set:
            return ac
```

only returns the first eleent of that list:

```
('forename1', 'surname1')
```

I can't understand why.

**Partial solution**

A partial solution, outputting all the three names, although in a raw format:

```
        academics_set = ResearchActivity.objects.filter(partner=obj.id).values_list('academic__forename', 'academic__surname').distinct()
        html = []
        for ac in academics_set:
             html.append("%s %s" % (ac[0], ac[1]))
        return mark_safe(html)
```

This outputs:

```
['person1', 'person2', 'person3']
```

I'd like to output:

```
<a href="/admin/academic/academic_1_id/change">academic name 1</a>, <a href="/admin/academic/academic_2_id/change">academic name 2</a>, <a href="/admin/academic/academic_3_id/change">academic name 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution I've managed to achieve:

@admin.display(description='Academic link(s)')
def get_academic_links(self, obj):

```
return format_html_join(
    ', ',
    mark_safe("<a href='/admin/artsdb/academic/{}/change/' target='_blank'>{} {}</a>"),
    ((ac['academic__id'], ac['academic__forename'], ac['academic__surname']) for ac in ResearchActivity.objects.filter(partner=obj.id).values('academic__forename', 'academic__surname', 'academic__id').distinct())
    )
```

I'd finally like to group the academics by ResearchActivity, although I can't seeem to find out how. If I change the queryset to `ResearchActivity.objects.filter(partner=obj.id)` and then access `ac.academic`, I don't have any input.